# Query the two cities in STATION with the shortest and longest CITY names,

Tags: sql, oracle

Query: Query the 2 cities contained in STATION table with the shortest and longest CITY names, as well as their respective lengths (i.e.: number of characters in the name). If there is more than one smallest or largest city, choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.

[image]

where LAT_N is the northern latitude and LONG_W is the western longitude.

Sample Input :

Let's say that CITY only has four entries: `DEF, ABC, PQRS and WXY`

Sample Output:

```
ABC 3
PQRS 4
```

Comment: this looks like an exercise question. show what you have tried to solve this.

Comment: yep I agree wiht vkp what have you tried?  Hint you don't need nested or aggregate functions either so I untaged those.  LENGTH() is the function that will give you the length of the city

Comment: (select city, length(city)
 from station
 order by length(city) asc
 limit 1
) union all
(select city, length(city)
 from station
 order by length(city) desc
 limit 1
);

Comment: above query worked for mysql but for oracle it is not working when i used top instead  of limit

Comment: What Oracle version? (query `select * from v$version` to find out) Oracle 12 has something similar to `limit 1`, called `fetch first|last`; in Oracle 11 and below, it is a little more complicated.

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: select s.city , length(s.city) from station as s join (select min(Length(s.city)) as minl , max(length(s.city)) as maxl from station s) ss on Length(s.city) in (ss.minl,ss.maxl) ORDER BY length(s.city) desc , s.city limit 2

Comment: A simple solution for MYSQL server: 

SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) FROM STATION ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY), CITY ASC LIMIT 1;

SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) FROM STATION ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) DESC, CITY ASC LIMIT 1;

Comment: one more solution with SQL server: SELECT TOP 1* FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 CITY,LEN(CITY) C1 FROM STATION ORDER BY LEN(CITY) ASC,CITY ASC) ONE
GROUP BY CITY,LEN(CITY), C1
HAVING LEN(CITY) = MIN(LEN(CITY))
UNION
SELECT TOP 1* FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 CITY,LEN(CITY) C2 FROM STATION ORDER BY LEN(CITY) DESC,CITY DESC) TWO
GROUP BY CITY,LEN(CITY), C2
HAVING LEN(CITY) = MAX(LEN(CITY))

Comment: select city,length(city) from station where id  IN ((select id from station order by length(city) desc, city limit 1),(select id from station order by length(city) asc, city limit 1));

Answer (score 56):

TRY THIS :)

mysql code.... simple one

```
select CITY,LENGTH(CITY) from STATION order by Length(CITY) asc, CITY limit 1; 
select CITY,LENGTH(CITY) from STATION order by Length(CITY) desc, CITY limit 1;
```

**Edit:**

The above solution is not working for me as it doesn't sort alphabetically. As commented by `@omotto` the following is the proper way to make it work. I have tried in SQL server and it works.

```
select top 1 city, len(city) from station order by len(city) ASC, city ASC; 
select top 1 city, len(city) from station order by len(city) DESC, city ASC;
```

Comment: @Moudiz It is, in fact, an answer, just didn't use code formatting - I edited to fix that.

Comment: So ordering by length, auto-alphabetically orders same length names?

Comment: @Tolga did you find the answer?

Comment: This solution It's not ordering alphabetically:

MS SQL solution:


select top 1 city, len(city) from station order by len(city) ASC, city ASC;
select top 1 city, len(city) from station order by len(city) DESC, city ASC;

Comment: @omotto your solution works as it sorts the items alphabetically ... not sure how all people have voted up that answer as it doesn't work

Comment: (select city, LENGTH(city) from station order by LENGTH(city) asc, city asc limit 1)
union
(select city, LENGTH(city) from station order by LENGTH(city) desc, city asc limit 1) 
               -----this is what I did

Comment: This works well in MS SQL Server but not Oracle.

Comment: I used the first code with the UNION clause and works fine to me in MySQL

Answer (score 12):

For MS SQL Server:

```
Declare @Small int
Declare @Large int
select @Small = Min(Len(City)) from Station 
select @Large = Max(Len(City)) from Station
select Top 1 City as SmallestCityName,Len(City) as Minimumlength from Station where Len(City) = @Small Order by City Asc
select Top 1 City as LargestCityName,Len(City) as MaximumLength from Station where Len(City) = @Large Order by City Asc
```

For Oracle server:

```
select * from(select distinct city,length(city) from station order by length(city) asc,city asc) where rownum=1 union
select * from(select distinct city,length(city) from station order by length(city) desc,city desc) where rownum=1;
```

Comment: Without using `distinct`, The solution for oracle works fine.

Comment: (Select  city,length(city) from  station 
where length(city) = (select min(length(city)) from station  ) order by city limit 1)
union
(Select  city,length(city) from  station 
where length(city) = (select max(length(city)) from station) order by city limit 1)

Answer (score 7):

```
( select CITY, 
       char_length(CITY) as len_city 
  from STATION 
  where char_length(CITY)=(select char_length(CITY) 
                          from STATION 
                          order by char_length(CITY) LIMIT 1) 
  Order by CITY LIMIT 1) 
 UNION ALL 
 (select CITY,
        char_length(CITY) as len_city 
  from STATION 
  where char_length(CITY)=(select char_length(CITY) 
                           from STATION 
                           order by char_length(CITY) DESC LIMIT 1)  
  Order by CITY DESC LIMIT 1) 
  ORDER BY char_length(CITY);
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation as to why this answers the question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @Carpetsmoker will add the explanations anymore whenever i post an answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
select min(city), len
  from (
        select city, length(city) len,
               max(length(city)) over() maxlen,
               min(length(city)) over() minlen
          from station
       )
 where len in(minlen,maxlen)
 group by len
```

Subquery gets the list of cities and it's length. At the same time ["window functions"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) `min/max over()` get minimal and maximal length for all rows in set (table). Main query filter only cities of length is min/max. `min(city)` with the group by `len` gives the result first name on the alphabetical order.

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your code, so the OP can learn from it.

Comment: @EBH Ok. updated. I not speak english. Please correct my answer if it contains grammatical errors.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way to do it using the always handy `row_number` analytic function:

```
with cte as (
  select city,
         length(city) as len,
         row_number() over (order by length(city), city) as smallest_rn,
         row_number() over (order by length(city) desc, city) as largest_rn
    from station
)
select city, len
  from cte
 where smallest_rn = 1
union all
select city, len
  from cte
 where largest_rn = 1
```

Comment: Correct answer for your hackerrank test case is : 


 SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) 
  FROM STATION
  ORDER BY  LENGTH(CITY) ASC, CITY ASC
  LIMIT 1; 

 SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) 
  FROM STATION
  ORDER BY  LENGTH(CITY) DESC, CITY ASC
  LIMIT 1;

Comment: Another way is to use row number function and derived table...
SELECT city, lencity FROM
(
select city, len(city) lencity, row_number() over (order by len(city) ASC, city) shortestCitySort, row_number() over (order by len(city) DESC, city) largestCitySort
from station
    )A  where A.shortestCitySort = 1 OR A.largestCitySort = 1 order by lencity

Comment: Tested and passed successfully

SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) AS noofchar
FROM STATION
ORDER BY noofchar, CITY ASC
LIMIT 1;

SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) AS noofchar
FROM STATION
ORDER BY noofchar DESC, CITY ASC
LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 4):

```sql
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT city, length(city) 
  FROM station
  WHERE LENGTH(city)=(SELECT MIN(LENGTH(city)) FROM station) ORDER BY city ) 
  WHERE ROWNUM =1;
```

```sql
  SELECT city, LENGTH(city) 
  FROM station  
  WHERE LENGTH(city)=(SELECT MIN(LENGTH(city)) FROM STATION) 
  AND ROWNUM=1
  ORDER BY CITY;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a minute to read through [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) - this looks helpful but it would benefit from some explanation of what the code does, consider [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41385887/edit)-ing that in?

Comment: SELECT 
    CITY,
    L
FROM (
SELECT
    CITY,
    LENGTH(CITY) AS L,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY),CITY) city_length_mn,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) DESC,CITY) city_length_mx
 FROM STATION
) A WHERE A.city_length_mn = 1 OR A.city_length_mx = 1
ORDER BY CITY;