# Select shortest and longest string

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to select the shortest and longest strings by characters in a table?

I have a `CITY` column of type `VARCHAR(20)` and I want to select the shortest and longest city names in alphabetical order by length.

I did like this

```
SELECT CITY,LENGTH(CITY)
FROM STATION
WHERE LENGTH(CITY) IN (
    SELECT MAX(LENGTH(CITY))
    FROM STATION
    UNION
    SELECT MIN(LENGTH(CITY))
    FROM STATION
)
ORDER BY CITY ASC;
```

When ordered alphabetically, Let the CITY names be listed as ABC, DEF, PQRS, and WXY, with the respective lengths 3,3,4, and 3. The longest-named city is obviously PQRS, but there are options for the shortest-named city; I have to select ABC because it comes first alphabetically.

My query ended up with all three CITY having length 3.

```
 ABC 3
 DEF 3
 PQRS 4
 WXY 3
```

The result of SELECT must be

```
ABC 3
PQRS 4
```

Comment: LIMIT 1, to get at least 2 cities? What about ties?

Comment: Its duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397411/sql-query-for-finding-the-longest-name-and-shortest-name-in-a-table

Comment: @LAVKUMARVISHWAKARMA, note that the linked question is for some other dbms than MySQL.

Comment: @jarlh There are many answers for mysql, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query for finding the longest name and shortest name in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397411/sql-query-for-finding-the-longest-name-and-shortest-name-in-a-table)

Comment: @steffen, Oops, notíced that now when I scrolled down. Sorry LAVKUMARVISHWAKARMA.

Comment: What difference does 'alphabetical order' make? You mean if you have two cities 'Paris' and 'Milan', pick 'Milan'?

Comment: this looks like a hacker rank sql challenge

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Anyway i got the answer

```
SELECT CITY,LENGTH(CITY)
FROM STATION
WHERE LENGTH(CITY) IN (
  SELECT MAX(LENGTH(CITY))
  FROM STATION
  UNION
  SELECT MIN(LENGTH(CITY))
  FROM STATION
)
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) DESC,CITY ASC LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: What if you have a table with 6 cities: `XXX`, `YYY`, `ZZZ`, `OOOO`, `AAAAA`, `BBBBB`? Your query effectively becomes `SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) FROM STATION WHERE LENGTH(CITY) IN (5, 3) ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) DESC, CITY ASC LIMIT 2;` You would just get `AAAAA` and `BBBBB` as the results, which are the two longest city names, not the longest and the shortest.

Comment: If you want the Hacker Rank solution, this one works.

Answer (score 10):

I know you have chosen your answer already, but here is a shorter answer that might help.
This is using Microsoft MySQL Server but it can also be easily translated to any other type using the call LIMIT instead of TOP.

**Shortest Length**

```
SELECT TOP 1 CITY, LEN(CITY)
FROM STATION 
ORDER BY LEN(CITY) ASC, CITY ASC;
```

**Longest Length**

```
SELECT TOP 1 CITY, LEN(CITY)
FROM STATION 
ORDER BY LEN(CITY) DESC, CITY ASC;
```

Comment: MySQL and  Microsoft SQL Server are different products.

Answer (score 4):

Try these queries.

Longest City Name::

```
select CITY from STATION where char_length(CITY) = (select max(char_length(CITY)) from STATION)
```

Shortest City Name::

```
select CITY from STATION where char_length(CITY) = (select min(char_length(CITY)) from STATION)
```

Answer (score 3):

I read the comment of Midhun Manohar above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50813334/11129060

I'm kind of a newbie so these are easier for me to understand:

```
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY)
FROM STATION
WHERE LENGTH(CITY) IN (
    SELECT MAX(LENGTH(CITY))
    FROM STATION
)
ORDER BY CITY ASC LIMIT 1;
                    
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY)
FROM STATION
WHERE LENGTH(CITY) IN (
   SELECT MIN(LENGTH(CITY))
   FROM STATION
)
ORDER BY CITY ASC LIMIT 1;
```

or another post seems to be easier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41285068/11129060

```
select CITY,LENGTH(CITY) from STATION order by Length(CITY) asc, CITY limit 1; 
select CITY,LENGTH(CITY) from STATION order by Length(CITY) desc, CITY limit 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

I have tried this and found the solution for MySQL database query,

```
(SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY)
FROM STATION 
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) ASC, CITY ASC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT  CITY, LENGTH(CITY)
FROM STATION 
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) DESC, CITY ASC LIMIT 1)
```

I think it is better to use LIMIT than row number.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `union` with subquery if I understand correctly :

```
select s.*
from station s
where length(city) in (select max(length(city)) 
                       from station 
                       union 
                       select min(length(city)) 
                       from station)
order by length(city);
```

Comment: I edited with the help of your answer @yogesh-sharma

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) FROM STATION ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY),CITY LIMIT 1;

SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) FROM STATION ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) DESC, CITY LIMIT 1;
```

The above code should easily work out and be easy to understand. The first query displays the shortest city name and its length. The second one outputs the longest.

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL, you can use:

```
(select CITY, length(CITY) as len from STATION order by len, CITY ASC limit 1)
union
(select CITY, length(CITY) as len from STATION order by len DESC, CITY ASC limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION operator

```
(SELECT CITY, MAX(LENGTH(CITY)) FROM STATION)
UNION
(SELECT CITY, MIN(LENGTH(CITY)) FROM STATION)
GROUP BY CITY ASC LIMIT 1;
```

More examples https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Comment: yep my mistake instead of ORDER I meant GROUP

Answer (score 0):

I found this one simple:

```
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) FROM (SELECT CITY FROM STATION ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) ASC, CITY ASC) 
WHERE ROWNUM=1;

SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) FROM (SELECT CITY FROM STATION ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) DESC, CITY ASC) 
WHERE ROWNUM=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

please find this below query :

```
SELECT top 2 CITY,LEN(CITY)
FROM STATION
WHERE LEN(CITY) IN (
  SELECT MAX(LEN(CITY))
  FROM STATION
  UNION
  SELECT MIN(LEN(CITY))
  FROM STATION
)
ORDER BY LEN(CITY) DESC,CITY ASC ;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Much cleaner way:

```
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) FROM STATION ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) ASC, CITY ASC LIMIT 1;
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) FROM STATION ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) DESC, CITY ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In mssql server, it should be this.

```
SELECT TOP 2 CITY, LEN(CITY) FROM STATION
WHERE LEN(CITY) IN (
    SELECT MAX(LEN(CITY)) FROM STATION
    UNION
    SELECT MIN(LEN(CITY)) FROM STATION
)
ORDER BY LEN(CITY) DESC, CITY ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CITY,LENGTH(CITY)
FROM STATION
WHERE LENGTH(CITY) IN (
  SELECT MAX(LENGTH(CITY))
  FROM STATION
  UNION
  SELECT MIN(LENGTH(CITY))
  FROM STATION
)
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) DESC,CITY ASC LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
(SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) 
FROM STATION
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) ASC, CITY ASC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) 
FROM STATION
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) DESC, CITY DESC LIMIT 1);
```

This gives you result something like this:

```
ABC 3
PQRS 4
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be simplified in this sql query below.

```
(select city, length(city) from station group by city order by length(city), city limit 1)
union
(select city, length(city) from station group by city order by length(city) desc, city desc limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For SQL Server 

SELECT CITY,TXTLEN
FROM 

(

SELECT  RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CITY ASC) IDX,CITY ,LEN(CITY) TXTLEN FROM STATION 
WHERE LEN(CITY) IN ( SELECT MIN (LEN(CITY))  FROM STATION) 

UNION 

SELECT  RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CITY DESC) IDX,CITY ,LEN(CITY) TXTLEN FROM STATION 
WHERE LEN(CITY) IN ( SELECT MAX (LEN(CITY))  FROM STATION) 

) AS FIN WHERE IDX=1 ORDER BY TXTLEN
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The following code works in Oracle SQL. All the above solutions did not work for **Oracle SQL** btw! You may add Union in between. But this runs fine as well!

```html
SELECT * FROM 
          (SELECT city,LENGTH(city) 
          from station 
          order by Length(city), city)
WHERE rownum <= 1; 
SELECT * FROM
          (SELECT city,LENGTH(city) 
          from station
          order by Length(city) desc)
WHERE rownum <= 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

HERE IS ONE

```
WITH t1 AS ( 
    SELECT MAX(LENGTH(city)) AS Max_length_city ,
    MIN(LENGTH(city)) AS Min_length_city 
    FROM station 
) 
SELECT city,LENGTH(city)
FROM station
WHERE LENGTH(city)=(SELECT Max_length_city FROM t1) OR LENGTH(city)=(SELECT Min_length_city FROM t1)
ORDER BY LENGTH(city) DESC,city ASC LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select CITY, LENGTH(CITY) FROM STATION 
WHERE ID IN (
SELECT ID FROM(Select ID,CITY,CLEN,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CLEN ASC) AS RW FROM(
Select ID,CITY,LENGTH(TRIM(CITY)) CLEN, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY LENGTH(CITY) ORDER BY CITY) 
    rnk from STATION ORDER BY CITY) WHERE rnk =1 order by CLEN asc) WHERE RW =1 
)
UNION ALL 
Select CITY, LENGTH(CITY) FROM STATION 
WHERE ID IN (
SELECT ID FROM(Select ID,CITY,CLEN,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CLEN ASC) AS RW FROM(
Select ID,CITY,LENGTH(TRIM(CITY)) CLEN, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY LENGTH(CITY) ORDER BY CITY) 
    rnk from STATION ORDER BY CITY) WHERE rnk =1 order by CLEN asc) WHERE RW = (SELECT 
                                                                                MAX(RW) FROM(Select ID,CITY,CLEN,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CLEN ASC) AS RW FROM(
Select ID,CITY,LENGTH(TRIM(CITY)) CLEN, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY LENGTH(CITY) ORDER BY CITY) 
    rnk from STATION ORDER BY CITY) WHERE rnk =1 order by CLEN asc)) 
)
```

Comment: Hello there! Welcome to the Stack Overflow.  thank you for answering questions. please add some explanation to your answer to be more helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for MS SQL Server**

select city, len(city)
from station
where city in (select top 1 city from station
order by len(city), city union
select top 1 city from station
order by len(city) desc , city asc );

Answer (score 0):

```
select CITY, LENGTH(CITY) from STATION ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) ASC, CITY ASC LIMIT 1;
select CITY, LENGTH(CITY) from STATION ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) DESC, CITY ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Simple And Short